# Auto-scroll on div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve got a CSS problem that I can't deal with since I'm very bad at it. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/5/) I made to show you the issue. When you click the send button several times you can see that the `<div>` doesn't autoscroll and that messages are hidden.

I tried something like this:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("mainblock");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

It stills does the same (like in the fiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

[JS Fiddle DEMO:](https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/7/)

I added:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 5000 }, 2000);
```

This is just a simple example. Be sure to include the jQuery library.
I'm sure there are a more elegant way. Please around a bit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In  case I'll receive messages instead of sending, is there a way to put this line of code not in a function but make it global ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your scroll is actually on the Body element

try using this:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];    
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/6/)

On the Other Hand You can use your javascript with this css added to your app:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
    max-height: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

[Example2](https://jsfiddle.net/kz935gge/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your JavaScript

```
 window.scrollTo(300, 500);
```